# Add multiple hyper-v switch to a windows container?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-network, windows-container

I have a Windows server 2022 with docker installed and i need to run some windows container. One of these windows container needs to have access to two network interface of the host server. I did set up two Hyper-v switches, so when I run
`docker network ls` 
I get the following

[image]

The BackEndHyperV is how the container access to the database, and the frontend i how it exposes it's service (rest-API on port 5000)

In my docker-compose.yml, I tried a few options, but none worked. The latest I tried is :

```
services:
  hawaii:
    image: "registerycontainerdatastore.azurecr.io/dockerapibuilder:latest_dev_noentrypoint"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - "C:\\source\\REST_API:C:\\App\\dab-config.json"
    environment:
      - DAB_ENVIRONMENT="C:\App\dab-config.json"
    networks:
      - BackEndHyperV
      - FrontEndHyperV
```

But I get the following error:
"service "hawaii" refers to undefined network BackEndHyperV: invalid compose project"

Why is docker telling me the network is not existing but I can display it using docker network ls?

Also i used the powershell command `Get-NetAdapter` to show the Net adapter and i got :

[image]

Regards

Vincent